# How to access a variable from one function to another function?

Tags: function, python-3.x

How do i access x from callx to callxAgain?
code:

```
def callxAgain():
    print(x)

def callx():
    x = 1
    callxAgain()

callx()
```

Comment: pass it as a parameter...

Answer (score 0):

You need to  pass the value of x into the callxAgain() function:

```
def callxAgain(x):
    print(x)

def callx():
    x = 1
    callxAgain()

callx()
```